# Table Sorting with JavaScript Only

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

How can I make this function work for a table with 3 columns on th click, in a simple way? And when the user click th again the table should be sorted descendent. No jQuery allowed or other libraries.

```
function sortData() {
    var tableData = document.getElementById('data_table').getElementsByTagName('tbody').item(0);
    var rowData = tableData.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for (var i = 0; i < rowData.length - 1; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < rowData.length - (i + 1); j++) {
            if (parseInt(rowData.item(j).getElementsByTagName('td').item(0).innerHTML) > parseInt(rowData.item(j + 1).getElementsByTagName('td').item(0).innerHTML)) {
                tableData.insertBefore(rowData.item(j + 1), rowData.item(j));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this function to sorting tables like a thousand years ago, before jquery even existed (I think):

```
function tableSort(table, column, initrow, lastrow, descending){
    var value1, value2;
    var tbl = document.getElementById(table);
    for(i = initRow;i < lastRow;i++){
        x = i;
        for(j = i+1;j < lastRow + 1;j++){
            value1 = tbl.rows[j].cells[column].innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(',','.');
            value2 = tbl.rows[x].cells[column].innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(',','.');
            if(!isNaN(value1)){
                value1 = parseFloat(value1);
                value2 = parseFloat(value2);
            }
            if(!descending && value1 < value2){x = j;}
            else{
                if(descending && value1 > value2){x = j;}
            }
        }
        tbl.tBodies[0].insertBefore(tbl.rows[x], tbl.rows[i]);
    }
}
```

---

table: the id of the table you want to sort

column: the index of the column you want to sort

initrow: from which row start to sorting

lastrow: to what column finish to sorting

descending: the sorting orientation (boolean value you can setup somewhere else toggling it)

---

example:

```
<table id='mytable'>
    <th>my first column</th>
    <th desc='false' onclick='tableSort("myTable", 2, 1, 10, this.desc)'>my second column</th>
    <tbody>  <!-- important!!!! -->
         <tr>... etc ...</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you run a jQuery plugin: dataTable. It's really helpful in sorting table and has added feature you might also need in the future. :D hope it helps :) link here: http://www.datatables.net/